# unicode character for a with e above it

Tags: unicode, diacritics, ligature

The letters ä, ö, ü in German were written (e.g., in Gutenberg's Bible) with the respective vowels that had a tiny e printed right above them. Are these characters available in Unicode? They looked something like:

```
e  e  e  e  e  e
A  O  U  a  o  u
```

If they are not available in Unicode as single glyphs, perhaps they can be "produced" using Unicode control characters? For example, I thought of using Unicode character 1d49 ("MODIFIER LETTER SMALL E"), but the glyph does not appear above the previous vowel, but on its upper-right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a "control code" but a Unicode Combining Diacritical Mark, U+0364.

Answer (score 0):

0364 is in hex = 868 decimal, so in Word type your letter, then hold down the ALT key; type 0 8 6 8; release the ALT key and the e is added above the preceding letter